# Creating new CanvasView

Tags: android, methods, main-activity

I am a beginner in programming... so maybe this question sounds funny to you.
I have a problem on creating a new CanvasView inside the MainActivity because it has something written inside its brackets.
Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CanvasView myView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //the line below doesnt work
        myView = new CanvasView();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void button1(View v){
        CanvasView.l = 400;
        myView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and here is my CanvasView:

```
public class CanvasView extends View{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    static int l = 500;

    public CanvasView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(100,100,l,100,paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create yout canvas after super.onCreate and setContentView like below

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
myView = new CanvasView();`

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean with your first line:  "super.onCreate method. "